# How Can I Keep A Label From Truncating?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm animating a `Label`'s translation to scroll it horizontally when it's text is too long to be displayed, but I'm facing an issue... The label truncates the long text when I use `LineBreakMode="NoWrap"` which makes the scrolling pointless.

```
<Label 
    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
    Text="this text is getting cut off because its too long to be displayed"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

[image]

I've tried setting the MinimumWidthRequest to an absurdly large number, but no help.

How can I make the label expand it's width to the total length of the text and disable truncating?

Comment: I believe the `CenterAndExpand` will constrain the label to the area of the container, which will cause it to truncate the text. Possibly using `Center` instead would maintain the auto width which would size the label to it's content and the container would crop it. (allowing you to animate it via margins or such, but I would suspect `Center` might interfere with that as well.)

Comment: could it work ?

Comment: I ended up creating a control with SkiaSharp

Answer (score 1):

**NoWrap** – does not wrap text, displaying only as much text as can fit on one line

so if your content is too long,it still truncate it.

if you want to let the long text label display on one line and could scroll  automatically.

you could write a [CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction) to achive the effect.

create a custom **MarqueeLabel** :

```
public class MarqueeLabel :Label
{
}
```

create a custom TextView **MaqueeText** in Android.Project:

```
class MaqueeText :TextView
{
    protected MaqueeText(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }
    public MaqueeText(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    public MaqueeText(Context context, IAttributeSet attribute) : base(context,attribute)
    {

    }
    public MaqueeText(Context context, IAttributeSet attribute,int style) : base(context,attribute,style)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsFocused => true;

}
```

create custom renderer **MaqueeTextRenderer**  in Android.Project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MarqueeLabel), typeof(MaqueeTextRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class MaqueeTextRenderer :LabelRenderer
    {
      Context context;
      public MaqueeTextRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
          this.context = context;
        }
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
          if (Control != null)
           {
             MaqueeText maqueeText = new MaqueeText(context);
             maqueeText.SetSingleLine(true);
             maqueeText.SetMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
             maqueeText.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.Marquee;
             maqueeText.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
             SetNativeControl(maqueeText);
           }

        }

     }
}
```

in ios,similar to Android,you could install NugetPackage **MarqueeLabel.iOS**.then in your custom renderer :

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MarqueeLabel), typeof(MarqueeLabelRenderer))]
 namespace Test.Forms.App.iOS.Renderer
  {
     public class MarqueeLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
      {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
         {
           var x = new MarqueeLabel.iOS.MarqueeLabel();
           SetNativeControl(x);
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
         }
     }
  }
```

finally in your page.axml:

```
  <local:MarqueeLabel Text="asdsdsaddsdjkfkjfldjfdfjldkfsdkf;kfd;kdf;sdkf;skf;skf;sdkf;dkf;fk;dfk;dfk;fk;fk;fk;dfk;fkfsdfk"></Label>
```